# I have a public key and a JWT, how do I check if it's valid in Go?

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I have a public key from my identity provider

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
THIS
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And a JWT token from my client.

How do I check the token against the key?
I'm having difficulty with `jwt-go` because the Parse function takes the token string and a `getKey` function.

Not sure how exactly to proceed

Comment: There is no public or private key, when you work with JWT. There is just a secrect. https://jwt.io/

Comment: No. You could use RSA algorithm to sign, it needs a pair of private key and public key to sign and verify.

Comment: I have proof of concept to use `jwt-go` to sign a token using private key and public key for verification. it might help, you can check it here https://github.com/Keda87/golang-echo-jwt-rsa

Answer (score 16):

The token was signed by RSA algorithm that uses a private key to sign and a public key to verify. Store your public key to the files system and use `jwt.SigningMethodRS256.Verify()` to verify. As the following snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    jwt "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func main() {
    publicKeyPath := "~/public_key.key"
    token := "your_jwt_token_here"

    if isValid, err := verifyToken(token, publicKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if isValid {
        fmt.Println("The token is valid")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("The token is invalid")
    }
}

func verifyToken(token, publicKeyPath string) (bool, error) {
    keyData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(publicKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    key, err := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(keyData)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    parts := strings.Split(token, ".")
    err = jwt.SigningMethodRS256.Verify(strings.Join(parts[0:2], "."), parts[2], key)
    if err != nil {
        return false, nil
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `jwt-go`, you can do this

```
token, err := p.Parse(IDToken, func(*jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte(signingKey), nil
})
```

And it will verify the token against the key.

Quoting the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Keyfunc),

> type Keyfunc func(*Token) (interface{}, error)
>
> Parse methods use this callback function to supply the key for verification. The function receives the parsed, but unverified Token. This allows you to use properties in the Header of the token (such as `kid`) to identify which key to use.

Comment: if I generate JWT token with private key as my signing key, then it should be use the private key for the verification, isn't? and the question is how to verify using public key if I have JWT token generated from private key

Comment: Hi @AdiyatMubarak. No, verifications are done with public keys. The private key should only be known by the signer, who then sends the public key to verifiers/receivers of signed messages. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_authentication

Comment: Thank you @Ullaakut. will take a look at that. Seems like I misconfigured my project which still does not work.

Comment: Previously I used raw byte from my private key for signing, then verifying with a raw byte from my public key, but it failure on verification. but it works now after I changed the signing and verify key using `*rsa.PrivateKey` and `*rsa.PublicKey`. thank you for pointing out @Ullaakut

Comment: No worries! :) Good luck and have fun with JWT authentication!